# vcenter server for windows 5.5 upgrade to 6.0 fails with error 1603

Tags: vmware-vcenter, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade our vcenter server wich is currently running 5.5u2e to version 6.0 
But the upgrade throws the following error message during installation:

> VMware Message Bus Configuration Service failed firstboot.
>   Unable to connect to Authorization Service: Failed to connect to Authorization Service:
>   uri:https://vcenter.ourdomain.com:443/insvc
>   Failed to register with CM
>   Restart Inventory Service to enable the authorization checks

and finally fails with the following message:

> Installation of component VCSServiceManager failed with error code 103.
>   Check the logs for more detailes.

Inspecting the logs nothing really caught my eye and restarting the Inventroy service during installation have not changed the result of the upgrade process.
And i verified that my odbc is working correctly.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this behaviour ?

Comment: Have you tried calling VMware?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me following a support call to VMWare.

- After rolling back to vSphere 5.5
- Ensure the SSO machine is joined to the domain and connectivity to the domain controller is proper.
- Restart the VMware Identity Management Service - this will ensure IDM picks up the current domain join state.
- Using the vSphere Web Client, remove the Active Directory (IWA / machine integrated) identity source.
- Now add the Active Directory (IWA) identity source - if it auto-detects the domain name as "WORKGROUP", the domain join state is still not correct (you may need to reboot and try again, or try leaving and rejoining the domain).
- Once successfully added, proceed with the vSphere 6.x upgrade.